# Repeatedly dividing individuals into groups

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose that I have $n$ individuals and wish to divide them into groups. Each group has $k$ members. (We may assume that $n$ is a multiple of $k$ so there are no individuals 'left over'.) Furthermore, suppose that I want to split the $n$ individuals into the groups $t$ times; and I don't want any individual to be in the same group with any other individual twice. How large does $n$ have to be?

Note: the problem above arose when I was designing an experiment (with $k = 4$ and $t = 5$). While I am mainly interested in the solution for these parameter values, I have posed the more general problem for the benefit of future readers.

**Edit:** This seems to be equivalent to the [social golfer problem](http://web.archive.org/web/20050407074608/http://www.icparc.ic.ac.uk/%7Ewh/golf/solutions.html#2-2-3). In the case of $k = 4$ and $t = 5$, one can achieve the division outlined above using just $n = 16$ participants.

Comment: Does each run occurs at the same time for different person? It doesn't matter for the specific case of $k=4, t=5$, as the answer will still be $n=16$. But it will change the answer significantly for other cases.

Comment: Yes: there are $t$ rounds, and in every round we simultaneously divide the $n$ individuals into groups of $k$.

Comment: I don't suppose you could explain why $n = 16$ when $k = 4$ and $t = 5$? This seems a little low to me.

Comment: $n=16$ is correct for $(k,t)=(4,5)$. See "4 groups of 4 golfers in 5 weeks" in the document you linked.

Comment: Thanks for spotting, you are right!

Comment: It is surprising to me that $n = 16$ is possible. Clearly, $n \geq 16$ since each person will be matched with $3 \times 5 = 15$ others.